# How to edit a page in cms that isn't there?

Tags: magento2, frontend

I just uploaded a quick start magento+theme on my server and now I have this list of pages and none of them corresponds to the home page. 
[image: The home page in question is full of content.]

The home page in question is full of content, But when I browse through content-> pages all of them in "content" have nothing but a div with "page-content" "display:none"

[image]

what am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

Login to admin panel.

```
Store > Setting > configuration > Web Tab > Default Page
```

check your current home page from dropdown.

```
Field CMS Home Page
```

You will find your's home page.

Comment: I found the page and all it has is 
<div class="page-content"><em style="display: none;">page-content</em></div> 

:(

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find this content in CMS block.

So try checking cms blocks in admin panel:

> Content > Elements > Blocks

Comment: I also tried that, and also tried looking into the page-content class in CSS. 

I also tried erasing this DIV from the content of the page.. All of the content it's still there even after I cleaned and flushed cache. This doesn't make any sense

Comment: @Yago Massiah Which theme are you using?

Comment: It's called Kobe

Answer (score 0):

the process is simple. Just access your backend, go to settings -> configurations and from there, navigate to default page of you web tab. There you can find your homepage in the drop down menu.

Good luck.